# Forward decoded POST data to other URL using Express

Tags: express

Some background information:

I have a temperature sensor which is connected via LoRaWAN.
The data from the sensor is encoded, but the manufacturer of the sensor provides a decoder (node app).
I want to show the data in [Thingsboard](https://thingsboard.io).

Now I was thinking to build a simple express API (I'm new to Express) as a kind of middleware.
The only purpose is to receive the encoded data, decode it (output is in JSON format), and pass it on to Thingsboard.

With the last step I need some help. This is my route:

```
const decoder = require('../helpers/decoder');

module.exports = app => {
  app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const data = {
      type: req.body.productType,
      payload: req.body.payloadValue
    };

    const jsonData = decoder.decode(data.type, data.payload);

    // jsonData needs to be forwarded/redirected Thingsboard
  });
};
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction, how to pass on the "handled" POST data and pass it on to another URL (Thingsboard HTTP endpoint URL)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is not the best practice**, but if you want to read some data from some route in another route without passing them when the route was called then you can try this code below:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.post('/', (req, res) => {

  app.locals['decoder'] = { data: "This is my decoder data"};

  res.send('Successfully to add decoder data');
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(app.locals['decoder']);
} )

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is up');
});
```

⚠️ **It should be noted** that the code above is only an example of how to read data from one route on another route.

**Another option:**

‍ You can create a middleware that is used to decode your `payload` and use the middleware on each route that requires the results of the decoded `payload`.

⚠️ But, it should be noted that for this problem, you must leave a `payload` on each route that requires decoded results, so that it can be decoded.

**Updated: Passing Data To External Endpoint**

If You want to pass the data to an external endpoint or another website, see code below:

```js
const axios = require('axios');

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  const decoder = { data: "This is my decoder data"};
  // method of external-endpoint: e.g: POST
  axios.post('https://www.example-website.com/api/v1/example-endpoint', decoder)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    }).catch(ex => {
      console.log(ex);
    })
})
```

You can use that route above in the example express server in addition to this answer.

I hope it's can help you .